# Cannot select WSO2 artifacts for CAR file

Tags: eclipse, wso2, pom.xml, artifact, composite-application

I am trying to package my composite application in WSO2 but the pom file is being shown as a standard eclipse pom, not a WOS2 pom.
This makes it very difficult to be able to choose which artifacts to include in my CAR file.

Is there a way to fix this other than potentially reinstalling WSO2?

[This is my pom file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SFTn.png)

[This is what it should look like (from colleague):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMWIm.png)

I appreciate any help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

`Right clicking the POM` -> `Open with` -> `Composite Application Project POM Editor`

Comment: Thank you, his solved my issue! It seems WSO2 decided to change my default editor to the Maven pom editor without telling me.